# Creating a pipeline with user inputs, pipleline as a service

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

we have requirement user will give steps for builds, need to capture this data and build source code for pipeline[Jenkins] an tools to achieve this ?

pipeline as service setup steps for above requirement. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to clarify the question to add more details.
But if I got it correctly please read:

- https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/01/08/mpl-modular-pipeline-library/
- https://github.com/griddynamics/mpl

Comment: 1. user key in inputs [env variables, checkout, build ....]

Comment: 2.need to build source code for pipeline based on inputs
Any tool is there to achieve this kind of req